# Is there a way to elegantly "swap" rows in all foreign key and many to many fields in django?

Tags: django

I have a class let's call it `Entity` it's a container for a label and a type and then I have many other models like `Store`, `Purchase`... And they have a relationship like so:

```
class Store(Model):
 store_name = TextField()
 entities = ManyToManyField(Entity)

class Purchase(Model):
 datetime = DatetimeField(auto=True)
 entity = ForeignKeyField(Entity)
```

In this case, say that I have an entity that I end up wanting to "swap" for instance, at some time I had "CocaCola" and then I have "Coca Cola", the user decides hey these two are the same, let's "merge them", effectively what I need to do is delete CocaCola or Coca Cola and swap all the keys out

so....

```
for p in Purchase.objects.filter(entity=cocacola_entity):
 p.entity = coca_cola_entity
 p.save()
for s in Purchase.objects.filter(entities=cocacola_entity):
 s.entities.remove(cocacola_entity)
 s.entities.add(coca_cola_entity)
 s.save()
cocacola_entity.delete()
```

Is there a better way to handle this in a global context? I.e. "Django magically fetch me EVERYTHING with this row as a foreign key and swap it with the other one)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `update()` to update the foreign key:

```
Purchase.objects.filter(entity=cocacola_entity).update(entity=coca_cola_entity)
```

You can also pass multiple items to `add()`, and then clear the other relation in case of a many-to-many field:

```
coca_cola_entity.store_set.add(*cocacola_entity.store_set.all())
cocacola_entity.store_set.clear()
```

Answer (score 0):

Django doesn't have anything like this built-in to do this magically. However, you can write a couple of functions to make this easier to do:

```
def swap_field(model, field, old_val, new_val):
    """Swaps the field values of a field
    model:   Model class
    field:   Name of the field
    old_val: Old (current) value of the field
    new_val: New value to set on the field
    """

    for obj in model.objects.filter(**{field: old_val}):
        setattr(obj, field, new_val)
        obj.save()

def swap_m2m(model, field, old_val, new_val):
    """Swaps the field values of a ManyToManyField"""

    for obj in model.objects.filter(**{field: old_val}):
        m2m_field = getattr(obj, field)
        m2m_field.add(new_val)
        m2m_field.remove(old_val)
```

---

Usage:

```
swap_field(Purchase, 'entity', cocacola_entity, coca_cola_entity)

swap_m2m(Store, 'entities', cocacola_entity, coca_cola_entity)
```

If you need to update many models, you can make a loop:

```
models = [ModelA, ModelB, ModelC, ...]

for model in models:
    swap_m2m(model, 'entities', cocacola_entity, coca_cola_entity)
```